# Is there a difference between 平和 and 平安

Tags: word-choice, words

Is it like 平安 is used mainly when talking about the 平安時代 or in terms of historical peace?

Comment: What do you mean by "historical peace"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese, we can see the following trend

> 平安 1644 results, with more particular results being
>
> - 平安時代 668
> - 平安京 194
> - 平安末 55
> - 平安後期 40
> - 平安朝 85
> - 平安神宮 28
> - 平安初期 36
> - 平安貴族 35
> - 平安宮 9
> - 平安期 16
> - 平安文化 6
> - 平安中期 33

In other words, 平安 seems to be primarily used as a reference to the Heian period.

It *can* be used to mean "calm" (as opposed to "peaceful" 平和), but for this purpose 平穏 is more common:

> 平穏 500 results (already more than for 平安, after subtracting the specific list above)